# Error while building an application(.EXE) using LabVIEW 2018 32bit

Tags: build, labview

While I'm trying to build an application using LabVIEW, the following error occurs and the build is aborted:

> **"Error 7 occurred at Invoke Node in AB_Engine_Write_Linker_Wrapper.vi->AB_Build.lvclass:Copy_Files.vi->AB_Application.lvclass:Copy_Files.vi->AB_EXE.lvclass:Copy_Files.vi->AB_Build.lvclass:Build.vi->AB_Application.lvclass:Build.vi->AB_EXE.lvclass:Build.vi->AB_Engine_Build.vi->AB_Build_Invoke.vi->AB_Build_Invoke.vi.ProxyCaller
>   Possible reason(s): LabVIEW: (Hex 0x7) File not found. The file might
>   be in a different location or deleted. Use the command prompt or the
>   file explorer to verify that the path is correct.
>   ========================= Nonexistent GPIB interface. Method Name: Linker:Write Info To File"**

I've tried resolving all the arising conflicts and also tried to create a new application, but still the build is aborted midway with the same error.

Please suggest the possible solutions for resolving the error.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried this https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000PA8kSAG&l=en-IN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error should never happen -- it indicates a bug in LabVIEW. The most common reason is you have enabled the options to "remove typedefs" and/or "remove poly VIs" and/or "remove unused VIs", and LabVIEW removed something it should not have removed (NI seems to make this mistake regularly with new features -- poor testing!). Try disabling those options (I believe they're enabled by default). You may wish to contact technical support via [the NI forums](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/bd-p/170) to get more assistance (they may even have a patch for this by now since since you're reporting it against LabVIEW 2018).